# Removing "[<content>]"s from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

So I want to take a string and remove all []s from it as well as any text/chars inside those []s, but only ones that come after the name.  I'm not sure if I should use regex or another method.
Examples:

```
"Name []"` to `"Name"
"Another name [text123]"` to `"Another name"
"Yet another name [a] [] [c]"` to `"Yet another name"
"[So many names] [test] []"` to `"[So many names]" 
"[TITLE] name []"` -> `"name"
"[txt2] [namez] [] a"` -> `"a"
```

Comment: What have you tried? I'd use a String::replace with a regexp.  Also this will help you https://regex101.com/#javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its going to take some regex running.

Example is as follow

```js
var originalStrings1 = '[So many names] [test] []';
var originalStrings2 = '[TITLE] name []';

console.log(getName(originalStrings1));
console.log(getName(originalStrings2));

function getName(str)
{
 var hasName = str.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/gm, '');
 var noName = str.match(/\[(.*?)\]/gm);
 if(isEmpty(hasName))
 {
  return 'Name is: '+noName[0];
 }
 else
 {
  return 'Name is: '+hasName.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
 }
}

function isEmpty(str)
{
 return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length == 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd of course use REGEX, faster, stronger, and easier.

Below is a working snippet:

```js
var str = "Yet another name [a] [] [c]";
var res = str.replace(/\[.*\]/i, " ");
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: I wonder why the down vote?! My code snippet addresses the user concern exactly and does solve their problem.

Comment: You should not use **greedy** mode. Per OP's request, `"[TITLE] name []"` should return `"name"`.

Comment: @Leo, I wonder how that can condition be fulfilled **taking in consideration** that the OP would also want `[So many names] [test] []` to return `So many names` !!!

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant OP want it to return `[So many names]` not `So many names`, its a lot of different

Comment: Yes @rachmatsasongko, excuse me. I get your point, that was a TYPO in my above comment. `[So many names] [test] []` returning `[So many names]` is the problem actually and I really doubt there is  single REGEX that can fulfill all requested examples without using being **greedy**.